# What is mean by @file tag in dockblock

Tags: php, comments

I am using phpCheckstyle [phpcheckstyle](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fphpcheckstyle%2F&ei=hjfGU6qgDsKjugSu3YHgAQ&usg=AFQjCNGYGRgxEKT2PkErUK2qNwPsORPQaw&sig2=tmu8W_Oo0bgi1ThW6Fo1Qw&bvm=bv.71126742,d.c2E) for standardizing my code commenting. After validating file in warning it suggests 
"Doc block comments should include information about file(@file) for each PHP file"
The warning resolves when adding @file tag -- I want to know what value should I assign to this tag (What it indicates).

And what is the difference between @file and @filesource

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to code standards `@file` is a `Doc-Block` comment (for each file) and is a description of what this file is intended for.

For example, imagine your model file Users.php with all its methods, well, you can put in your file comment something like this:

```
/**
 @file
   This file will store all model methods to recover/update/delete Users.php
 ....
*/
```

@filesource, afaik, is similar to @example tag, you can take a look to pear documentation [here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.filesource.pkg.html)

Comment: `@file` is not now a recognized tag in phpDocumentor, and I can't find an archive indicating if ever was - https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`@file` is not a [recognized tag](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/index.html).

It's ironically hard to find and navigate documentation on the subject.

But https://pear.php.net/package/PhpDocumentor/docs/latest/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.pkg.html suggests that the DocBlock for a file would be the first DocBlock in the file:

> An example:
>
> ```php
> 1. /**
> 2.  * tags demonstration
> 3.  * @author this tag is parsed, but this @version tag is ignored
> 4.  * @version 1.0 this version tag is parsed
> 5.  */
> ```

… and that there is no need to specifically annotate it as such.